# Pinging a device

Tags: privacy

Forgive me if any of my terminology is incorrect but I have a question. I have a scan app on my phone to tell me of any network routers or other device are in the area. Usually it will show up with my iphone and my ipad on the scan result. Lately there has been a network router that has been coming up on the scan. I pinged the router and it did respond. My question is how do I see where that router is? I do not have wifi except for hotspot so I don't think it's mine   I'm a little freaked out. Am I reading into this too much?

Comment: I must have missed your response, could you please re-add the additional information you want? It is not showing in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The device could be just a new gadget or someone has setup a new router somewhere that you are also detecting but much like you, I always want to know at least the proximity of the device.

A solution from server-fault previously: https://serverfault.com/questions/88946/is-it-possible-to-find-the-physical-location-of-a-wireless-router-based-upon-the

Unfortunately not all of us have access to commercial software so I normally load kismet on a few Raspberry-pi units and move them around the building in order to perform a rough triangulation along with my laptop. Its a manual process, but it works out well enough since I can gauge signal strength from the different units to locate the device.

You could always go all out like this guy: http://space.io9.com/using-physics-to-find-the-perfect-router-location-1627029102 But if you do, PLEASE write a howto!